# Fetching data in React's useEffect() returns error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am tryin to display data like this :

```
    import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
    const Slider = ({ getData }) => {
        
    useEffect(() => {
       getData.map(item =>
         console.log("data : ", item)
       )
      }, []);
        
     return (
       <div className='slider__container'>
          // { listItems }  
       </div>
     )
   }
        
export default Slider
```

To see clear, here is my **app.js** where i called my  component :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Slider from './Slider';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [loadSlide, setLoadSlide] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const handleclick = () => {
    setLoadSlide(loadSlide + 1)
  }

useEffect(() => {
    handleclick();
    fetch('/data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) =>  {
        setData(json.lvmh.slider)
        // console.log(json.lvmh.slider)
    });
}, [1]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Slider title={`titre: ${loadSlide}`} getData={ data } />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My json looks like this :

```
 "lvmh": {
      "slider": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "progressBar": "01 / 07 Inspirationd",
            "title": "Are you looking for a perfume",
            "img": "https://wallpapercave.com/w/wp8671030",
            "slider": [
               { "type": "Woman" },
               { "type": "Mixte" }]
         },...
```

in the chrome console it shows  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')** and sometimes `undefined`

Comment: I don't see where you define `data`

Comment: `getData` i meant, i made an update

Comment: What is getData? The problem is more likely not to be here. How are you passing getData to this component? listItems is also undefined

Comment: The problem is with `getData`. It's not clear where this is coming from and how you're passing it to your `Slider` component.

Comment: You should add `getData` to the dependency array. So probably your code starts out with `getData` being undefined, then it gets assigned a value on the next render. So it will be undefined given your `useEffect` is still referencing the old value of undefined

Comment: i added the app.js and the json file

Comment: Set data to an empty array `const [data, setData] = useState([]);`, and then do as Josh says and add `getData` to your `useEffect()` dependency array. You might not need to use `useEffect()` in `Slider` depending on what you're actually trying to do. Also that `.map()` should be `.forEach()` as you're not using the array `.map()` returns.

Comment: @NickParsons could you add it as an Answer please ? so i can validate it

Comment: Yes, now it's working  ! x) x)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//check getData is an array
const getData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  if(Array.isArray(getData)) {
    getData.map(item => console.log(item))
}
```

Comment: i added the app.js  and the json file to see clear

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

setState should be like this : `useState([]);`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import Slider from './Slider';
    import './App.css';
    
    function App() {
      const [loadSlide, setLoadSlide] = useState(0);
      const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      const handleclick = () => {
        setLoadSlide(loadSlide + 1)
      }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        handleclick();
        fetch('/data.json')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) =>  {
            setData(json.lvmh.slider)
            // console.log(json.lvmh.slider)
        });
    }, [1]);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Slider title={`titre: ${loadSlide}`} getData={ data } />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```